# Speed up splash screen imageView creation

Tags: android, image, optimization, splash-screen

I've created a simple splash screen for my app. It basically consists of a ImageView and two textViews. The imageView loads a backdrop image which is 2048x1365. The problem I'm having is when the app is launched I get a black screen (the android default) for a second or so while the view is rendered. I'm assuming this is to do with the time taken to load the image. Is there any way to speed this up so it jumps straight into the splash screen without having the second or so black screen while it renders the splash screen.

Here is the view code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:src="@drawable/backdrop"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="APP NAME"
            android:id="@+id/programSpecific"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="COMPANY NAME"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="40dp" />



    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Class

```
package co.uk.jameskrawczyk.testsplash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class splashscreen extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 4000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.spashscreen);

        //Define font for use
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/sourcesanspro.otf");


        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setTypeface(typeface);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.programSpecific)).setTypeface(typeface);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splashscreen.this,landingScreenClass.class);
                splashscreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                splashscreen.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set window background color. It will replace black color. Just add this line in your app theme:

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/app_background</item>
```

But I would recommend not to use higly detailed splash screen.